# Interpreting Partial Dependence Plot for Continuous Variable in Random Forest Model

Tags: random-forest

I am working with a Random Forest model to analyze survey data, aiming to identify significant variables that influence migration destination choices. Among my model's predictors, the number of family members is a key continuous variable.

After training the model, I generated the attached partial dependence plot (PDP) for the 'family members' variable. However, I'm struggling to interpret the plot and am uncertain about its validity.

[image: Partial Dependence Plot]

Could someone help me understand:

1. How to read and interpret this specific type of PDP?
2. What conclusions, if any, can be drawn about the relationship between the number of family members and the choice of migration destination?

Any insights, especially considering the context of Random Forest models, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. I'm not entirely certain if this question is on topic for this site, but in any case I think you may find more knowledgable people on other SE sites such as [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)